# How do i map godaddy domain name to AWS Application Loadbalancer?

Tags: dns, subdomain, aws-application-load-balancer, godaddy-api

We have a live website and we have configured godaddy domain to AWS instance with elastic IP, this configuration is working fine, now we are implementing a ALB with multiple ASG group and multiple traget group (one for API server and another for react APP).

Now AS ALB does not support fixed IP so could not map to godaddy domain name (a record). i have tried to map through route 53 but then saw that we have to replace godaddy name server to our aws name server, if I do replaced this name server record, then godaddy does not show all DNS configuration, so I fear that could lead us to stop working our email server on godaddy and all subdomain configured and hosted on another server.

Is there any other way to get a fixed IP address to map godaddy domain but dont want to loose that path based routing feature of Application loadbalancer.

Please let me know any possible way to achive both feature at same time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a CNAME record in godaddy.

Comment: As per my knowledge CNAME record is for sub-domain, but here i want to map my main domain. my main domain is already point to an elastic IP, now i want to map to my ALB